# Convert json to formatted string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, nginx, lua

I want to convert this json :

```
{
        "rate_limit_by": 
            [{   "type": "IP", 
                "extract_from_header": "X-Forwarded-For"
            }]
    }
```

to this:

```
"{\"rate_limit_by\": [{\"type\": \"IP\", \"extract_from_header\": \"X-Forwarded-For\"}]}".
```

**So that i can send it as part of payload in request in Python**.

And i have tried multiple methods for the same. json.dumps doesnt work cause it doesnt escape characters in this case & .replace(""",r"\"") doesnt work cause it creates the string like this :

```
{\\"rate_limit_by\\": [{\\"type\\": \\"IP\\", \\"extract_from_header\\": \\"X-Forwarded-For\\"}]}
```

---

(**Below is the example of curl but i want to send the data in specific format using python request.**)
My upstream expects data in certain format, as of now am sending data to upstream as below:

```
curl -i --request POST --data "rule_name=only_ip" \
--data-binary "@data.txt" \
--url http://localhost:8001/plugin/rules
```

Where data.txt looks like this:

```
rule={
        "rate_limit_by": [
            { "type":"IP", "extract_from_header": "X-Forwarded-For" }
        ]
    }
```

Am trying to convert it to :

```
curl -i --request POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary @data.json  http://localhost:8001/plugin/rules
```

Where data.json should like this

```
   {
        "rule_name" : "test_ip",
        "rule":"{\"rate_limit_by\": [{\"type\": \"IP\", \"extract_from_header\": \"X-Forwarded-For\"}]}"
    }
```

Now the value of "rule" is string with character escape. 
This am trying to achieve & am doing post using python.
And below is the code for same:-

```
import requests
import json
import re

url = 'http://localhost:8001/plugin/rules'
rule = {
        "rate_limit_by": 
            [{   "type": "IP", 
                "extract_from_header": "X-Forwarded-For"
            }]
    }

rule = json.dumps(json.dumps(rule))

print(rule) #this output the data in correct format

obj = {
        "rule_name" : "test_ip",
        "rule": rule #but when used it here its get wrapped in two \\
    }
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

print(obj) 

r = requests.post(url, data=obj, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: First, there's no such thing as a JSON object. Maybe you mean a JSON representation of a JavaScript object? Second, JSON is already a string.

Comment: Ok right thanks for the clarification, but can we come to real problem now ?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know what your real problem is, since you haven't explained it using words with understood meaning. It sounds like you want to convert JSON to a string--but JSON already _is_ a string, so there's no conversion to do.

Comment: @Flimzy i have updated the question can you have look at it once again ? Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`desired` is what you say you need in your something.json file. The following prints `True`. See https://repl.it/repls/DistantTeemingProtocol.

```py
import json

desired = r'''{
        "rule_name" : "test_ip",
        "rule":"{\"rate_limit_by\": [{\"type\": \"IP\", \"extract_from_header\": \"X-Forwarded-For\"}]}"
    }'''

d = {
    "rate_limit_by": [{
        "type": "IP",
        "extract_from_header": "X-Forwarded-For"
    }]
}

s = json.dumps(d)
xxx = json.dumps({"rule_name": "test_ip", "rule": s}, indent=4)
o = json.loads(desired)
yyy = json.dumps(o, indent=4)

print(xxx == yyy)
```

If you're going to POST using requests, then you should not be posting the string but should instead be posting the dictionary.

I.e.,

```py
r = requests.post(url, json={"rule_name": "test_ip", "rule": s})
```

Comment: Hey such great hack, so this seems to work when i print it but when pass it to value of some key it again gives \\ slash. Please have look at below code.

<code>
 rule = {
  "rate_limit_by": 
   [{  "type": "IP", 
    "extract_from_header": "X-Forwarded-For"
   }]
 }


rule = json.dumps(json.dumps(rule))

print(rule) -> this gives correct op
obj = {
     "rule_name" : "test_ip",
     "rule": rule <- when used here it again creates unwated \\
    }

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

print(obj) -> this fails. </code>
-----

Comment: sorry am unable to format my code in comment :(, this is my kinda first question on stack overflow.

Comment: So why did you want a JSON string if you were going to use the dictionary later on? Why not just use the original dictionary?

Comment: the \ is to escape the \ so that you can see it

Comment: its because i cannot send dictionary the way it is, i need to format it in specific format. Please look for the specific format which i have given as example in question. Do any other way to achieve the above format which i explain in question in this section :- [Where data.json should like this]

Comment: Edited the answer. Pick which `print(...)` at the end meets your needs.

Comment: actually i dont want to print it i want to send that as data of request body.

Comment: So send each and see which one is accepted by the recipient. You don't even show how you're sending the request body. Update your question to include how you are sending the "request body" so that we can understand what it is you are trying to do. Most likely, the way you are sending the "request body" is what's causing your difficulties.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel ohh thanks for this i have updated the question, can you have look at it once.

Comment: Sure it does. Let me edit the answer so that it compares the output to what you say you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to access the items inside somehow?

You should drop the "[]" because that part doesn't really make sense.

```
import json
x = str({
        "rate_limit_by": 
            [{   "type": "IP", 
                "extract_from_header": "X-Forwarded-For"
            }]
    })

x = x.replace("[","")
x = x.replace("]","")
x = eval(x)
d = json.dumps(x)
l = json.loads(d)
l['rate_limit_by']['type']
```

This outputs "IP". Now you have a dictionary of all you need called l.

Comment: can you give an example of one of the json that would be sent ?

Comment: Hey i have given it please look into the section of [Am trying to convert it to]